# Remove parts of object, which are inside of another object

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I want to remove the inside parts to retopo this model (made in nomad) properly:

[image]

The hair wrapping around the body is also inside the body:

[image]

I want to remove the parts of the hair inside the body.
What I tried:

1. Merge by distance (removed about 2500)
2. Select All by Trait -> Interior Faces, which looks like this:
   [image]

The vertices overlap and and aren't connected between the body and the hair. I guess that causes a problem. Sadly most of the posts I found on the internet were about more simple models, like a cube inside of another cube.

What method can I use to select the inside hair (or the inside parts of the eyes etc) and remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing this to retopo the model, I suggest to use the Voxel Remesher. It is found under *Object Data Properties > Remesh*. The most important parameter is the *Voxel Size* which you need to make as small as possible without producing a mesh that's too dense for your PC.

[image: Voxel Remesh]