# Can I easily keep just the external faces of this Mandalorian helmet to 3D print? (I don’t want any of the internal geometry)

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

[image]

I have a Mecabricks file of this helmet. Each virtual brick is a part of the model and I can delete all but the ones associated with the exterior but each brick has a lot of detail and so is impractical for 3D printing.

Literally all I need are the external faces so I can easily 3D print it.

Can I easily keep just the external faces of this Mandalorian helmet to 3D print? I don’t want any of the internal geometry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove parts of object, which are inside of another object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306165/remove-parts-of-object-which-are-inside-of-another-object)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43150/removing-internal-geometry-before-3d-printing